# How to prevent jQuery BlockUI from triggering

Tags: jquery, forms, onsubmit, jquery-blockui

I made [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/BXVDU/) to be triggered on every form submit action:

```js
$("form").submit(function() {
    jQuery.blockUI();
});
```

I want to validate some of the forms before they are submitted:

```html
<form method="POST" onSubmit="return(confirm('Really submit?'));">
```

When I hit "Cancel" on the confirm popup box, the BlockUI gets triggered and blocks the interface. It never gets unblocked.
Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8B8yA/.

The question is how to prevent BlockUI from getting triggered when "Cancel" is pressed.

I've tried adding `$.unblockUI()` to "Cancel" action:

```
if(!confirm("Really submit?")) {
    $.unblockUI();
    return(false);
}
```

but it obviously does not work, as the unblock action is called before the block action is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('skip'))
    jQuery.blockUI();
});​
```

and

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.blockUI.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" onSubmit="return (function(form) { var c = confirm('Are you sure?'); if(!c) { $(form).addClass('skip'); } return c; })(this);">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
<html>​
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/8B8yA/5/

Comment: That's it. This technique not only solves the problem but also allows re-usability. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try removing **onsubmit** from form and doing:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    if(confirm('Really submit?')) {
        jQuery.blockUI();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
});
```

Did you mean something like this:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8B8yA/2/)

You can add id to the form where you need block ui, like:

```
$("#yourFormId").submit(function() {
        if(confirm('Really submit?')) {
            jQuery.blockUI();
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: No. This will make _every_ of my forms be asked for confirmation before submitting. I don't want that.

Comment: `id` is a unique identifier. Imagine a page with more than one form. A class would be more appropriate. Besides, this won't solve the problem as BlockUI will be disabled _at all_ on some of the forms. I want to prevent it only when "Cancel" is pressed on JS confirm dialog box.